# How to trigger same Event in multipleTextBox

Tags: jquery

i have 4 textbox which i would like to trigger all at the same time

```
 var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
  e.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
                        $("#txtBox1").trigger(e);                      
                        $("#txtBox2").trigger(e);                     
                        $("#txtBox3").trigger(e);                     
                        $("#txtBox4").trigger(e);
```

The only thing that is working is txtBox1 , how can i trigger all these events?

Thanks, have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yZ6BV/)**

```
$("#txtBox1, #txtBox2, #txtBox3, #txtBox14").trigger(e);
```

If you have multiple ids with common pattern as show then you can use attribute selector.

```
$('[id^=txtBox]').trigger(e);
```

The class selector is very useful in this kind of situation. You can assign a common class and use [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind and trigger the event.

```
$('.common-class').trigger(e);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it depends if class selector could be used, suppose he can not change the html. But I agree with you in most of cases class selector is best choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest, since you're using jQuery, is to simply put them all into the same selector:

`$("#txtBox1, #txtBox2, #txtBox3, #txtBox4").trigger(e);`

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aNnGv/